# How can I get userstories not linked to test case? Is there any query? I tried already with linkedissues

Tags: jira, jira-plugin, jql

I need User Stories which are not connected to test cases

linkedissuesofall
linkedissues
epicof
paerentsof

project = system-aaa AND type = Story AND "Numer inicjatywy" = 111  AND fixVersion in releaseDate('on 2009/01/01') and issueFunction not in linkedIssuesOf("type='test case'")

Answer (score 0):

Using [TestRay SynapseRT](https://goldfingerholdings.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/SRT/pages/25985683/synapseRT+JQL+Reference), you can simply use the JQL below:

```
project = 'projectname' AND issue not in hasTestCases() AND issuetype = 'User Story'
```